# Analyzing Accelerometer / Gyroscopic Data

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

I have created a data logger that logs acceleration and Gyroscopic data on to an SD card. The logged data is about 1.5GB in the form of txt files.  I wish to perform thorough analysis on this data via graphs but I do not know what tools can be used to achieve this. I am interested in proprietary or open source tools to get my work done. I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Matlab, Excel, pgfplots, matplotlib, Mathematica, ScyLab to mention a few. You should narrow down what product you need or tell us what kind of analysis is on your mind. For example, do you need to filter the data, auto and cross correlate it, or just view it?

Comment: What are you trying to learn from your data?  It's difficult to guide you without this information.

Comment: Honestly with this volume of data (GB), you're better off asking on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ But be prepared to explain what your "thorough analysis" actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already use Mathcad or Matlab, use those for the learning curve.

If you are starting from scratch, then use Python, with mathplotlib for plotting, and numpy and possibly scipy for data analysis. These have the best learning curve, complete libraries, consistent behaviour across libraries, and will stand you in the best stead for the future. By comparison, Perl is inconsistent, C is just hard work.

You might want to have a little look first to see what you have with a spreadsheet.